# AppenChild dynamic h3 to dynamic div issue

Tags: javascript, html

I try to insert a dynamic h3 to a dynamic div, hovewer something is odd as it gets inserted outside the lblUser div. I would also like to be inserted after the "Role" h3.

Here is my code :   function showUsers() {

```
  lblUserList.innerHTML = "";

  for ( var i = 0; i < ajUserDataFromServer.length; i++ ) {

      var lblUser = document.createElement('div');

      lblUser.innerHTML = '<div class="lblUser">' + '<img src="' + ajUserDataFromServer[i].image + '" alt="user" class="lblUserImage" data-userImage="' + ajUserDataFromServer[i].image + '">' + '<h3 class="lblUserId">' + 'Id:' + ' ' + ajUserDataFromServer[i].id + '</h3>' + '<h3 class="lblUserRole" data-userRole="' + ajUserDataFromServer[i].role + '">' + 'Role:' + ' ' + ajUserDataFromServer[i].role + '</h3>' + '<h3 class="lblUserName" data-userName="' + ajUserDataFromServer[i].name + '">' + 'Name:' + ' ' + ajUserDataFromServer[i].name + '<h3 class ="lblUserLastName" data-userLastName="' + ajUserDataFromServer[i].lastname + '">' + 'Lastname:' + ' ' + ajUserDataFromServer[i].lastname + '</h3>' + '<h3 class="lblUserPassword" data-userPassword="' + ajUserDataFromServer[i].password + '">' + 'Password:' + ' ' + ajUserDataFromServer[i].password + '</h3>' + '<button id="btnEditUserBody" class="btnShowPage btnEditUser" data-userId="' + ajUserDataFromServer[i].id + '" data-showThisPage="pageUpdateUser">' + 'EDIT USER' + '</button>' + '<button class="btnDeleteUser" data-userId="' + ajUserDataFromServer[i].id + '" >' + 'DELETE USER' + '</button>' + '<h3 class="lblErrorMessage" id="lblDeleteUserErrorMessage">' + '</h3>' + '</div>';

        if ( ajUserDataFromServer[i].email ) {

        var lblUserEmail = document.createElement('h3');     
        lblUserEmail.innerHTML =  '<h3 class="lblUserEmail" data-userEmail="' + ajUserDataFromServer[i].email + '">' + 'Email:' + ' ' + ajUserDataFromServer[i].email + '</h3>';

        lblUser.appendChild( lblUserEmail );

        }

       if ( ajUserDataFromServer[i].phonenumber ) {

        var lblUserPhoneNumber = document.createElement('h3');     
        lblUserPhoneNumber.innerHTML = '<h3 class="lblUserPhoneNumber" data-userPhoneNumber="' + ajUserDataFromServer[i].phonenumber + '">' + 'Phone-number:' + ' ' + ajUserDataFromServer[i].phonenumber + '</h3>';

        lblUser.appendChild( lblUserPhoneNumber );

        }


        lblUserList.appendChild( lblUser );


    }

}
```

Comment: You don't close `img` and `h3` tag in `lblUser.innerHTML`. Try fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see a few things wrong with the code, for example:

```
var lblUserEmail = document.createElement('h3');     
lblUserEmail.innerHTML =  '<h3 class="lblUserEmail" data-userEmail="' + ajUserDataFromServer[i].email + '">' + 'Email:' + ' ' + ajUserDataFromServer[i].email + '</h3>';
```

Should be something like:

```
var lblUserEmail = document.createElement('h3');  
lblUserEmail.classList.add("lblUserEmail");
lblUserEmail.setAttribute("data-userEmail", ajUserDataFromServer[i].email);
lblUserEmail.innerText =  'Email:' + ' ' + ajUserDataFromServer[i].email;
```

Now you can append it:

```
lblUser.appendChild(lblUserEmail);
```

If you do it your way you wil get nested `h3` and `div` elements.

Furthermore, you need to close your img tag. I can advice creating those tags either in code or with the new [es5 string interpolation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) this will clean up your code and will show you these types of errors.

Comment: Thank you. That worked fine. But now is appended after the button elements. So how would you append that h3 into a specific position? I want it to be after the role h3 which is the 3rd element in the div. That would say I want the h3 to be in the 4th position.

Comment: I would personally append them in the right order, but if you need to insert after or before a specific element you have these three options: `.insertBefore()`, `.insertAdjacentElement()` or `.insertAdjacentHtml()`